# How to remove an input value before submitting it in Wordpress with the Ultimate member plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, hook, ultimate-member

I want to know how to remove an input value before submitting a profile form in Wordpress with Ultimate Member plugin. I've been stuck with this for a whole week.

The thing is that I have conditional fields in the profile form that if the user does not select, they still save their values ​​when the form is submitted. The plugin does not remove the values ​​from the hidden fields conditionally, which is a problem if you want to send these fields elsewhere with REST API.

I couldn't do it with PHP so I added a script inside the principal function to try and clear the values. This work when user refresh the form, but not when user submit the form [with the hook um_after_user_updated](https://docs.ultimatemember.com/article/1038-umafteruserupdated)

```
function remove_before_send () {
        ?>
            <script>
                var elements = document.querySelectorAll('.um-is-conditional');
                for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
                elements[i].childNodes[1].childNodes[0].value = "";
                }
            </script>
        <?php
}
add_action('um_profile_content_main', 'remove_before_send');
```

EDIT:
Thanks to the comment of @JB_DELR. You really gave me all the clues.
This is my final code (im not proud, because i wanted to use php, but this is the best i could do)

```
function remove_before_send () {
        ?>
            <script>
                var boton = document.querySelector("div.um-left.um-half > input");
                boton.addEventListener("click", function(){
                var elements = document.querySelectorAll('.um-is-conditional');
                for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
                if (elements[i].style.display == "none") {
                elements[i].childNodes[1].childNodes[0].value = "";
                }
                }
                });
            </script>
        <?php
}
add_filter( 'um_profile_content_main', 'remove_before_send');
```

Comment: Your js script need to handle the form submit event, prevent default submiting, remove unnecessary fields an submit the form itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your js script need to handle the form submit event, prevent default submiting, remove unnecessary fields an submit the form itself.

Something like this:

```
<script>
var form = document.querySelector(<select the form>);
form.onsubmit = function(e) {
   e.preventDefault(); // don't submit the form right now;
   var elements = document.querySelectorAll('.um-is-conditional');
   for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
     elements[i].childNodes[1].childNodes[0].value = "";
   }
   // to remove element, this remove the input field, so field is no more in the request
   // elements[i].childNodes[1].removeChild(elements[i].childNodes[1].childNodes[0]);
}
form.submit();
</script>
```

Comment: Also. This works because your script is in Body. If you want to put the script in the head, you have to deal with the document onload event because, when it's in the head, the script is executed before the entire page load so without have your form ready.